# When Django deletes uploaded files from the temporary directory?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored):

> However, if an uploaded file is too large, Django will write the
>   uploaded file to a temporary file stored in your system’s temporary
>   directory. On a Unix-like platform this means you can expect Django to
>   generate a file called something like `/tmp/tmpzfp6I6.upload`. If an
>   upload is large enough, you can watch this file grow in size as Django
>   streams the data onto disk.

So I have uploaded several times the same big file to a view and got this:

```
vic@vic /tmp $ ls -l tmp*.upload
-rw------- 1 vic vic2 3436110 мая   14 18:31 tmpKdZrQl.upload
-rw------- 1 vic vic2 3436110 мая   14 18:31 tmpqLyBsy.upload
```

When these files are deleted from the temp directory?

I want to avoid bloating the temp directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To write these tempfiles, Django uses the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module in python.  You can see django's code in `django/core/files/temp.py`.

A django temp file is a [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile).  [Here's a link to the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/temp.py).   The default settings in that constructor (plus code that's in django) calls for the file to be deleted when it is closed.

So watch out for filehandle links; if they're not getting deleted, it is likely that your code is leaking the filehandle, and never closing it.

Comment: It's strange that the file is not deleted after the request is finished

Comment: File deletion doesn't have anything to do with the status of the request, it's about whether the filehandle is closed or not.  Double check and see if there are code paths that finish the request without closing that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added `request.FILES.get('file').close()` and the file is deleted

Comment: > File deletion doesn't have anything to do with the status of the request < I think it should. If the request is finished, the uploaded file should be closed anyway.

Comment: I disagree - sometimes you'll want to do time-intensive processing on a file.  Say the user uploads a file.  The response comes back quite quickly "OK, thanks got the file!" -- but processing needs to just start then, and run for some time.  If the file got deleted as soon as the request finished, you'd have to copy it elsewhere to do processing on it *BEFORE* issuing the response, which would be inefficient and clumsy (but conveninent sometimes)

Comment: @FrobberOfBits if you're concerned about I/O, you might like to use memory instead, and save directly to your destination. By increasing your FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE, Django will use InMemoryUploadedFile instead of TemporaryUploadedFile (python tempfile).